# Record mouse clicks on images

Tags: python, mouselistener

I want to write a program to display a 500 image sequence, when I click on the image, it records where I clicked and save it in a file. Any advice how to start?

Comment: Welcome yto stack overflow. Unfortunately your question doesn't comply with the general approach required of StackOverflow. You should make some attempt and show what you have tried. There must be some aspect of this that you have already tried, if so show your code. Read the tutorial on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to write custom code for your use case.. but here are some guidelines and pointers to how to accomplish that.

There are 2 libraries that support detecting and saving mouse clicks

1. PyHook: https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/
2. PyUserInput: https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput#intended-functionality-of-capturing-in-pyuserinput

The location of the click can then be saved in a file using standard file writing operations: www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python